# Time complexity of scipy.linalg.solve (LAPACK gesv) on large matrix?

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, scipy, time-complexity, lapack

If I use [`scipy.linalg.solve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html) (which I believe calls LAPACK's gesv function) on a ~12000 unknown problem (with a ~12000-square, dense, non-symmetrical matrix) on my workstation, I get a good answer in **10-15 minutes**.

Just to probe the limits of what's possible (note I don't say "useful"), I doubled the resolution of my underlying problem, which leads to needing to solve for ~50000 unknowns.  While this would technically run on my workstation once I'd added some more 10s of GBytes of swap, it seemed more prudent to use some HW with adequate RAM, and so I kicked it off on an AWS EC2 High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large... where it has been grinding away for the last **14 hours** (hey, spot instances are cheap) and it's impossible to tell how far through it is.

Unfortunately, I've no idea what the time complexity of the solvers involved is (my google-fu failed me on this one).  If it's O(N^2) then I'd have expected it to be done after around 4 hours; if it's O(N^3) then maybe it'll be done in 16 hours.  Of course that's interpreting N as the number of unknowns - which has quadrupled - the number of elements in the matrix has increased by a factor of 16!

And advice which will help me determine whether this has any chance of completing in my (project's) lifetime or not gratefully received!

Other info:

Sparse matrices aren't of interest here (my matrix is dense, and in any case scipy's don't work with more than `2**31` non-zero elements even on 64-bit).

I'm using Debian/Squeeze's scipy on the workstation, Ubuntu 12.04 on EC2.  Both 64-bit obviously.

Comment: gsev -> LU-decomposition -> wikipedia says complexity >~ O(N^2.4), but constant factors, etc.? If you want to speed this up, I would suggest you check out things like OpenBlas or Intel MKL. There more specialized packages too, espeacially for sparse matrices, not sure about dense.

Comment: Is that N the number of unknowns, or the number of elements in the matrix (which is number of unknowns squared) ?

Comment: Time complexity of DGESV for an NxN matrix is O(N^3).  See Table 3.13 here: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node71.html

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser : Put that as an answer and I'll accept it thanks! (If'd only thought to google DGESV instead of GESV I'd have found that.)  Anyway, my computing behemoth eventually yielded a nice result in ~20 hours, which is in pretty good agreement considering the different HW (and the bigger problem's access patterns might be an even worse fit to CPU caches etc etc).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The time complexity of DGESV for an NxN matrix is O(N^3). See Table 3.13 here:
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node71.html