# Difference between xxxxx_(), LAPACK_xxxxx() and LAPACKE_xxxxx() functions

Tags: c, lapack, lapacke

Let's say I want to use LAPACK to solve a system of linear equations in C (GCC).
I set up the problem as follows:

```
/* Want to solve Ax=b */
int n = ...;      // size
double *A = ...;  // nxn matrix
double *b = ...;  // length-n vector
int m = 1;        // number of columns in b (needs to be in a variable)
double *pivot;    // records pivoting
int info;         // return value
```

Now it seems I can use one of three functions to solve this problem.
The first one is this:

```
dgesv_( &n, &m, A, &n, pivot, b, &n, &info );
```

I was surprised to see that this did not require any `#include`s, which seems... weird.

The second function has almost the same signature, except for the prefix `LAPACK_` which I think causes less ambiguity and is possibly less error-prone:

```
#include <lapack/lapacke.h>
LAPACK_dgesv( &n, &m, A, &n, pivot, b, &n, &info );
```

Note that this requires me to include `lapacke.h`.

The third function changes the signature somewhat by returning `info` and not taking all arguments as pointers:

```
#include <lapack/lapacke.h>
info = LAPACKE_dgesv( LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, m, A, n, pivot, b, n);
```

Again, this function requires `lapacke.h`. It also requires linking to an extra library with `-llapacke`.
All three functions need `-llapack`.

I'm trying to figure out the differences between these functions.
I did some snooping around and I found the following macros in `lapacke.h` and related header files:

```
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(name,NAME) name##_
#define LAPACK_dgesv LAPACK_GLOBAL(dgesv,DGESV)
```

So it seems that `LAPACK_dgesv()` and `dgesv_()` are different names for the exact same function.
However, it appears `LAPACKE_dgesv()` is something else with possibly a different implementation, especially considering the fact it needs an extra library.

So my question is: what are the differences between these two functions?
The documentation says LAPACKE is a C interface for LAPACK, but then what about the function `dgesv_()`?
Clearly I can use it normally without needing LAPACKE and without compiling anything in Fortran, so how is that different?

Thanks.

---

**Update**

Curiously, the function `dgemm_()` (matrix multiplication) does not have any `LAPACK_dgemm()` equivalent.
What's going on?

Comment: DGEMM is not a LAPACK routine.  DGESV_ is the Fortran symbol assuming single underscore convention. You must use the right size integer for Fortran to call this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Notice that `LAPACKE_dgesv()` features an additional flag which can be `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR` (usual fortran order) or `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR` (usual c order). In case of `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR`, it just calls `LAPACK_dgesv()` directly. In case of `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR`, `LAPACKE_dgesv()` will transpose the matrix before calling `LAPACK_dgesv()`. It is not a new implementation of `dgesv_()`. Take a look at [lapack-3.5.0/lapacke/src/dgesv_work.c](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/dd9/lapacke__dgesv__work_8c.html) In this file, there are minor additional changes about error handling.
- `LAPACK_dgesv()` is defined in the header [lapacke.h](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/de/ddd/lapacke_8h.html) as `LAPACK_GLOBAL(dgesv,DGESV)`. The macro `LAPACK_GLOBAL` is defined in lapacke_mangling.h : it just wraps `dgesv_` and cares for naming convention if other conventions are used.

So, basically, the function `LAPACK_dgesv()` just requires the headers of lapacke. Compared to `dgesv_`, some problems related to naming conventions in libraries may be avoided. But `LAPACK_dgesv()` is exactly the same as `dgesv_()`. The function `LAPACKE_dgesv()` enlarges the scope of `LAPACK_dgesv()` to handle usual c matrix.But it still calls `dgesv_` in the end.

The function [`dgemm()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f.html) is part of the BLAS library. A wrapped c version `cblas_dgemm()` can be found in [CBLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/#_cblas) . Again, an additionnal flag `CBLAS_ORDER` is required, with possible values `CblasRowMajor` and `CblasColMajor`.

Comment: Ah, I guess that makes sense now. Calling LAPACKE a "C interface for LAPACK" confused me, but I guess that just means the functions are more C-friendly. So does this mean that the performance difference is negligible? (assuming LAPACKE uses column-major order at least)

Comment: Yes, the performance difference is negligible as `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR` is used. Regarding `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR` there are additionnal memory requirements due to the transposed matrices. The complexity of the transpose operation is [O(n^2)](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-matrix-transposition) and the complexity of dgesv is [O(n^3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660052/time-complexity-of-scipy-linalg-solve-lapack-gesv-on-large-matrix). So the performance difference can be neglected even if `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR` is used.